# Points only in the central line

Tags: vega-lite

I am using [this example named "Line Chart with Point Markers"](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/line_overlay.html) as reference, but not see other example or any clues about conditional or "selected by symbol" points.

The illustration shows a typical case  (see also [SPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control)) where I need only the blue central line with dots.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by layering filtered versions of the dataset. Modifying the example you linked to, it might look something like this ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AGVMbKAGsABDk1Q1ZtgDMzAVjMAVOLDMBhNghxJZNDZspOquNAhwlIoqSJgoqKAM6oJoMXGcRqYQlFAQxCAAvkpwslBsyjSyZGigAB41IDoRAKoBmKkAnnBI6tF2gYLKqcqxcNGYHThj6JiIOGzqSClFIB0NSGRk6nyzqRH+fQND6JY01uOT0yAAjgz+OnE6pIVKZYILDf1wg6kQHQhMNgpJQTKapWQ+SpLQorQRILq9VAAbVAyHUJgaoKuwlkYyU80q7VQmHUDDgKxJ-ggdgWCDQKJA-UEs0RaQYCEofwBQLMAF5eWYAOQAcQA8qLhYLCgBdIqonoYhKNS6pHFjCmLWTU2n00BMlnDWLszn-QGCMwAQgFIvFkplBVlQA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Stock prices of 5 Tech Companies over Time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"timeUnit": "year", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol == 'GOOG'"}]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol != 'GOOG'"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hum... Is perfect (!), but now lost zoom interface. It is not working with  `selection: { "grid": {"type":"interval", "bind":"scales"} }`... I am using fresh and stable versions:  *vega@5.11.1, vega-lite@4.12.0, vega-embed@6.7.1*.

Comment: The interval selection must be added to one of the layers.

Comment: Thanks @jakevpd. I added [a new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61668295/287948), to not pollute this chat.